# How to write images in PDF created using itext in their original size?

Tags: java, image, itext

I am using itext to create PDF's in java. I Can write images to PDF using java. How do I make sure that the size of the image is same as it was before writing it to the PDF.

e.g. if the image is of 32 X 32 pixels size. It should be like that only in the generated pdf.

Below is my code.

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);

Image img = Image.getInstance(photoLocation);

PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(img, false);
cell.setPadding(8);
cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
table.addCell(cell);
```

Comment: This is explained here http://www.concretepage.com/itext/add-image-in-pdf-using-itext-in-java

Comment: @JaySmith I checked the link. But, somehow the image written to pdf still seems to be bit larger as compared to original image. However, if I right click on image in pdf and save that image locally and check the dimension, then it  seems ok. What is wrong? Am I missing something or just getting confused?

Comment: @ashishjmeshram Maybe the image viewer you're using is defaulting to a different zoom level, compared to the pdf viewer in question?